# Ordering Taxonomies / Changing term_id

Tags: taxonomy, order, terms

I have a site where there are nearly 200 series (custom taxonomy) and roughly 10 items (posts) in each.

Each series is called 'Name: *Series Number* - One liner bout the series'.

When I use get_terms to get all series and order by name I get the order like this.

Name: 1
Name: 10
Name: 100
Name: 101
Name: 102
...
Name: 109
Name: 11
Name: 110

Any ideas on how to order this without having to add 001, 002 etc?

Alternatively when I order by ID it works perfectly since I added each series one by one after each other. The only issue is during that process I missed a series and only added it after having already added a few more series.

For example I was supposed to add series 121 but missed that and went on to add 122, 123,124 and then 121. Now when I order by ID I get 120, 122, 123, 124, 121, 125.

Tried manually changing the term_id in phpmyadmin without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/

This plugin does what you want, you can easily manage order.

Answer (score 0):

How about ordering by count?

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
) );
```

Reference: [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Comment: Each series has a different amount of posts within them. Series 62 for example has 2 posts while series 50 has 24. Ordering by count would put series 62 before series 50.